# How to use np.where() function based on comparison between values of 2 columns i.e. Total_Summer and Total_Winter columns and 3 arguments?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I tried the following code but it is not working

```
data['Better_Event'] = np.where(data['Total_Summer'], 'Summer', (np.where(data['Total_Winter'], 'Winter', (np.where(data['Total_Summer'], data['Total_Winter'], 'Both')))))
```

Neither is the following working

```
ata['Better_Event'] = print(np.where(data['Total_Summer'], data['Total_Winter'], 'Summer', 'Winter', 'Both'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one line, you can use `pandas apply` with:

```
df['Better_Event'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Both' if x['Total_Summer']  > 0 and x['Total_Winter'] > 0 else ('Summer' if x['Total_Summer']  > 0 else ('Winter' if x['Total_Winter'] > 0 else 'No')), axis=1)
```

But it would be a lot faster to vectorize it with:

```
df['Better_Event'] = 'No'
df.loc[df['Total_Summer'] > 0, 'Better_Event'] = 'Summer'
df.loc[df['Total_Winter'] > 0, 'Better_Event'] = 'Winter'
df.loc[(df['Total_Summer'] > 0) & (df['Total_Winter'] > 0), 'Better_Event'] = 'Both'
```

And if you insist using `np.where()` you can do (your problem was that you didn't write the condition in the first parameter of the `where` function):

```
data['Better_Event'] = np.where((data['Total_Summer'] > 0) & (data['Total_Winter'] > 0), 'Both', np.where(data['Total_Winter'] > 0, 'Winter', np.where(data['Total_Summer'] > 0, 'Summer', 'No')))
```

Comment: How to do it using np.where() function?

Comment: @SaimaSayyed Added now

Comment: @jezrael Yeah, I worked with another test-df and changed there the `and` to `&` but forgot to change it here. Fixed it

Comment: @SaimaSayyed - Can you add some sample data to question?

Comment: @Aryerez that's still not working, it's showing an error "TypeError: invalid type comparison"

Comment: @jezrael yes sure,
Create a new column Better_Event that stores 'Summer','Winter' or 'Both' based on the comparison between the total medals won in Summer event and Winter event (i.e. comparison between the Total_Summer and Total_Winter columns) using "np.where()" function.

Comment: @SaimaSayyed I've edited it, so it will take into consideration more than 0. Next time you post a question, please take the time to add the the question itself some of the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

If there are numeric values in columns and need compare them then use:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Total_Summer':[5, 2, 4],
                     'Total_Winter':[5, 3, 1]})

data['Better_Event'] = np.where(data['Total_Summer'] == data['Total_Winter'], 'Both', 
                       np.where(data['Total_Summer']>data['Total_Winter'], 'Summer', 'Winter'))
print (data)
   Total_Summer  Total_Winter Better_Event
0             5             5         Both
1             2             3       Winter
2             4             1       Summer
```

Or use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m = [data['Total_Summer'] == data['Total_Winter'],data['Total_Summer'] > data['Total_Winter']]
data['Better_Event'] = np.select(m, ['Both', 'Summer'], default='Winter')
```